# MySQL: does MyISAM have tablespaces?

Tags: mysql, myisam

Can i create tablespaces with a MyISAM table running on MySQL 5.1.30?

Answer (score 2):

Tablesspaces (in MySQL 5.1) are only supported for NDB and NDBCLUSTER, cf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-tablespace.html:

> The ENGINE parameter determines the storage engine which uses this
>   tablespace, with engine_name being the name of the storage engine. In
>   MySQL 5.1, engine_name must be one of the values NDB or NDBCLUSTER.

But you can tell MySQL which data- and index-dir to use for MyISAM, cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html:

> By using DATA DIRECTORY='directory' or INDEX DIRECTORY='directory' you
>   can specify where the MyISAM storage engine should put a table's data
>   file and index file. The directory must be the full path name to the
>   directory, not a relative path.